# Maven trying to download a local dependency

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I'm working on an API that depends on a small library I created in my project. In IntelliJ IDEA, it looks like :

PROJECT : myProject

- MODULE : mySimpleAPI (maven project + spring boot application)
- MODULE : mySmallLib (maven project)

I just added mySmallLib in mySpringAPI's dependencies.

But when I execute the spring-boot:run command, it tried to download the dependency from spring repositories. I tried in offline mode, but it also didn't work. How can I tell to maven that the dependency is already in the project and it doesn't need to download it ?

Comment: `mvn clean install` the lib then try again

Comment: @RC. You're right, I totally forgot that. thanks, it worked !

Answer (score 2):

run `mvn clean install` on "mySmallLib" project first. This will install the jar in your local maven repo. Then you can perform `mvn spring-boot:run` on "mySimpleAPI" project.

Answer (score -1):

Seems your code/library is not updating automatically. So you will need to update them manually.

Go to each sub module of your project and open pom.xml. now right click on the file and click on clean install.

[image: Sample maven clean install in IntelliJ]

Try running your application again, and it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.